# How can i route in App.js file to a page that has a different index.html?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to Reactjs and I need to route in the App.js file to a Component ('B' for example) and I would like component B to have a background color of the whole page different from the other components, so I would need to insert in the html tag of the file.html an id to indicate that the whole page (only of component B) has a certain background color. I think I need to make an app that has two different pages, and therefore two different "entry points" (one for App.js and the other for B.js), but I don't know how to do this and how to route to the new page inside the App.js.

Example:

```
class App extends React.Coponent{
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>                
             <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
}
```

Login.js should have a different index.html file than App.js.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML file should not have anything other than the  to load your react content. You may use two 'Container' to wrap your two different component

Your root html should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    .
    .
    .

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then your login component can have the whole control of the body like this (I am using functional component as example):

```
const Login = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="app" style={{bgColor: blue}}>
      your login code
    </div>
  )
}
```

For the rest of the component, you may add other routing into one 'container'. the route that render on this page will always inherit the style from the container:

MainApp.js

```
const MainComponent = (props) => {
  <div className="app" style={{bgColor: yellow}}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/home" />
      <Route path="/about" />
   </Switch>
  </div>
}
```

In your app.js, remove the exact path for /home, and call the container component

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>                
      <Route path="/home" component={MainApp}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

you may refer to [CoreUI ReactJS](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react) for full example